# How to apply text wrapping to Label that is inside a GridPane

Tags: java, oop, javafx

I'm trying to put a whole paragraph inside a `GridPane` cell. I've set `wrapText` to `true`; but seems it's not working, and it just cuts off the first sentence of the `Label` in the `GridPane` cell. How do I make it so that the whole paragraph is shown inside the `GridPane` cell? I also want the paragraph to be centered. Here's my code so for it:

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(TRANSITION);
ImageView backView = new ImageView(GameMenu.BUTTON);
ImageView ins1View = new ImageView(INS1);
ImageView ins2View = new ImageView(INS2);
ImageView ins3View = new ImageView(INS3);

Label firstLbl = new Label("Use WASD keys to move the character. Sample sentence sample sample sample sample. Sample sample sample sample.");
try {
    firstLbl.setFont(Font.loadFont(new FileInputStream(GameMenu.LIGHTFONT_PATH),15));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    Font font = Font.font("Arial Black", FontWeight.BOLD, 20);
    firstLbl.setFont(font);
}
firstLbl.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
firstLbl.setPrefWidth(230);
firstLbl.setPrefHeight(230);
firstLbl.setWrapText(true);
firstLbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

setLayoutX(0);
setLayoutY(0);

grid.add(ins1View, 0, 0, 1, 1);
GridPane.setHalignment(ins1View, HPos.CENTER);
grid.add(firstLbl, 0, 1, 1, 1);
GridPane.setHalignment(firstLbl, HPos.CENTER);
grid.add(ins2View, 1, 0, 1, 1);
grid.add(ins3View, 2, 0, 1, 1);

grid.setHgap(20);
grid.setVgap(20);
grid.setPadding(new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40));
```

Here's a screenshot of the application:

[image: Application screenshot showing label being cutoff]

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Please read the link and create a specialized complete application which replicates the issue via copy+paste with no change or addition (you don't need any special fonts or images for that).

Comment: SceneBuilder can be useful for prototyping UI, even if you don't use the FXML it can generate.

Comment: If it was me, I'd put the Label and the Image together into a "custom" component built on a VBox and then put those into the GridPane (or a FlowPane).  Also, this design is ignoring that Label can have both a graphic and a text component.  So why not just make a Label with the Image and the text and just put that in the GridPane?  Either approach could make the original problem moot, as there's much less interaction between the Image/Text construct and the GridPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that I hope can help.

I did not see any code where you made use of `RowConstraints` or `ColumnConstraints`. I think the key is to have row three have the follow `RowConstraints`

```
RowConstraints rowThree = new RowConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```

**Full Code**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {        
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(10);       
        
        RowConstraints rowOne = new RowConstraints(170);
        gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rowOne);
        RowConstraints rowTwo = new RowConstraints(15);
        gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rowTwo);
        RowConstraints rowThree = new RowConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rowThree);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
            columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(33);
            gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
        }
        
        StackPane spViewOne = new StackPane();
        spViewOne.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        gridPane.add(spViewOne, 0, 0);
        StackPane spViewTwo = new StackPane();
        spViewTwo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        gridPane.add(spViewTwo, 1, 0);
        StackPane spViewThree = new StackPane();
        spViewThree.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        gridPane.add(spViewThree, 2, 0);
        
        Label lblOne = new Label("Use WASD keys to move the character. Sample sentence sample sample sample sample. Sample sample sample sample.");
        lblOne.setWrapText(true);
        gridPane.add(lblOne, 0, 3, 1, 1);
        
        
        StackPane spPlaceHolder = new StackPane();
        
        Button btnBack = new Button("Back");        
        
        VBox.setVgrow(spPlaceHolder, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setMargin(gridPane, new Insets(30, 20, 0, 20));
        VBox.setMargin(btnBack, new Insets(0, 0, 30, 0));
         
        VBox root = new VBox(gridPane, spPlaceHolder, btnBack);
        root.setPrefSize(600, 582);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Output**

[image]

If you want the label to extend the three columns change `gridPane.add(lblOne, 0, 3, 1, 1);` to `gridPane.add(lblOne, 0, 3, 3, 1);`

**Note:** I just noticed that you do not have a row three. That space is your `HGap`. You should be able to use the same idea on the second row.

Comment: I am wondering why it is necessary to set row constraints for rowThree to `Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`?

Comment: From [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html), “GridPane provides properties for setting the size range directly. These properties default to the sentinel value USE_COMPUTED_SIZE”, so it would seem that you would not need to explicitly set that, though I guess you could do it for clarity.

Comment: Hello @jewelsea. That's probably true. I used SceneBuilder and copied the setting directly from there. It's default settings are `Min Height = 10`, `Pre Height = 30` and `Max Height = USE_COMPUTER_SIZE`. A label would not act according until I changed `Pre Height` to `USE_COMPUTER_SIZE`.  As you has stated, this may not be needed in pure code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems silly to try to do this via the GridPane when Label contains all of the functionality to handle the Graphic and Text itself.

This is Kotlin, but it should be fairly easy to see what's going on.  The GridPane section just loads in the Labels, which are configured with the Image and the Text.  Setting the rows to align at the top keeps everything tidy:

```
 class GridLabels() : Application() {
   override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
      primaryStage.scene = Scene(createContent())
      primaryStage.show()
   }

   private fun createContent(): Region = GridPane().apply {
      add(createLabel("sample3.png", "This is some long text that should do some wrapping"), 0, 0)
      add(createLabel("sample2.jpg", "This is also long text and it should wrap too and get to a third line"), 1, 0)
      add(createLabel("sample3.png", "No wrap here"), 2, 0)
      add(createLabel("sample2.jpg", "This is also long text and it should wrap too"), 3, 0)
      add(createLabel("sample4.png", "This is some long text that wrap even more than all of the other labels in the GridPane"), 0, 1)
      add(createLabel("sample3.png", "This is also long text and it should wrap too"), 1, 1)
      add(createLabel("sample4.png", "This should not wrap"), 2, 1)
      add(createLabel("sample3.png", "This is also long text and it should wrap too"), 3, 1)
      vgap = 6.0
      hgap = 6.0
      padding = Insets(20.0)
      rowConstraints += listOf(defaultRC(), defaultRC())
      val backgroundImage = Image(GridLabels::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/images/background2.jpg"))
      background = Background(BackgroundImage(backgroundImage, null, null, null, null))
   }
}

private fun defaultRC() = RowConstraints().apply {
   valignment = VPos.TOP
}

private fun createLabel(imageName: String, theText: String) = Label(theText).apply {
   graphic = GridLabels::class.java.getResource("/images/$imageName")?.toExternalForm()?.run { ImageView(this) }?.apply {
      fitWidth = 200.0
      isPreserveRatio = true
   }
   isWrapText = true
   contentDisplay = ContentDisplay.TOP
   setFont(Font.font("Arial Black", FontWeight.BOLD, 14.0))
   maxWidthProperty().bind((graphic as ImageView).fitWidthProperty())
}

fun main() {
   Application.launch(GridLabels::class.java)
}
```

Here the maxWidth of the Label itself is constrainted to the width of the Image, and the wrapping happens within that space.

It looks like this:

[image]